# Mapping a one to many relationship

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have two topics.

1 - Artists `<ArtistId, Artist>`

2 - TitleArtist - `<String, TitleArtist>` a TitleArtist consists of an artistId and a titleId

I am trying to figure out how to produce a table with the following structure.

ArtistsForTitle - `<TitleId, [Artist]>`

Reading the Artist stream as a table seems straight forward.

As for the TitleArtist I thought I would do a `selectKey` on the titleId then `groupByKey` and `aggregate` on it. What I don't understand is how to handle the removal of an artist from a title.

Answer (score 0):

You should read both input topics as `KTable` (not as `KStream`). First you do a foreign-key join, to get the Artist information (available as of 2.3.0 release) Afterwards you do a `groupBy()` with new key `TitleId` to collect a list of artist.

Using `KTables` gives you end-to-end update semantics. I assume that the removal from an artist from a title is a `<key,null>` message in the TitleArtist topic?